# The Below PHP code is not working for me

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a new user to my mysql database and login with it to create a new database.  I tried the following code.  But it results some errors.

```
<?php

$mysqli=new mysqli("localhost","username","password@123") or die(".........");

$mysqli->query("CREATE USER 'new_username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '123456';");
$mysqli->query("GRANT ALL ON db1.* TO 'new_username'@'localhost'");

$mysqli->close();

$mysqli=new mysqli("localhost","new_username","123456") or die(".........");

if($mysqli->query("Create database if not exists New_DB_Name")){

   "Failed creating new database: ".$mysqli->connect_errno();
    die();

}

$mysqli->select_db("New_DB_Name");
$mysqli->close(); ?>
```

and here is the errors

```
    Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'new_username'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/public_html/sign-up/conn.php on line 10

Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/public_html/sign-up/conn.php on line 12

Warning: mysqli::select_db(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/public_html/sign-up/conn.php on line 19

Warning: mysqli::close(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/public_html/sign-up/conn.php on line 20
```

**Edit:**  Actually its not creating new user. that's the trouble here.

Comment: Add error reporting after your queries and the connect.

Comment: There is no error in connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your database permissions.  The error says that sql user `username` does not have create user permission.

Creating a user is an unusual thing to do from a script, unless you want to be creating many, many users in an automated way.

Probably you want to use the admin interface to create needed username once and then use PHP scripting to create all the aspects of schemas:  databases, tables, indexes, etc.

Comment: Let me check with hosting provider

Comment: you are right , the permission has been blocked by the hosting provider. thanks for your answer. Who vote it down. Mine question is not violating terms

Answer (score 0):

Try replace `root` with `username`. Default mysql username is `root`.

if the user exists, you have to change this line:

`$mysqli->query("CREATE USER 'new_username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '123456';");`

with

`$mysqli->query("CREATE USER new_username@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '123456';");`

as mysql doesn't support `single quote` but support "``"

Answer (score -1):

You have a problem with the connection line:

```
$mysqli=new mysqli("localhost","username","password@123") or die(".........");
```

You cannot use `localhost` for the connection it must be `127.0.0.1`.

More information: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php

Comment: still the same error i replaced all the `localhost` with `127.0.0.1`. But no positive results.

Comment: localhost is the same as 127.0.0.1.  Why do you think one must be used and the other avoided?

Comment: @wallyk yes, it is the same, please follow the link I posted, the docs explicitly say that you cannot use `localhost`